# How to calculate third central moment?

Tags: python, statistics

**Description:** I have a sample: `sample = [100, 86, 51, 100, 95, 100, 12, 61, 0, 0, 12, 86, 0, 52, 62, 76, 91, 91, 62, 91, 65, 91, 9, 83, 67, 58, 56]`. I need to calculate **third** central moment of this sample.

**My approach:**

- I'm making a table with top row being unique values from the sample and bottom row - frequency of each value from the top row:

```py
table = dict(Counter(sample))
```

- Then I'm calculating empirical k-th central moment with this formula:
  [image: $\dfrac{\sum ^{N}{i=1}\left( x{i}-\overline{x}\right) ^{k}\cdot frequency_{i}}{N}$ (where $\overline{x}$ is general mean):]

```py
def empirical_central_moment(table: dict, k):
  mean = sum([value * frequency for value, frequency in table.items()]) / sum(list(table.values()))
  N = sum(list(table.values())) 
  return sum([(value - mean)**k * frequency / N for value, frequency in table.items()])
```

**Program:**

```py
from collections import Counter

def empirical_central_moment(table: dict, k):
  mean = sum([value * frequency for value, frequency in table.items()]) / sum(list(table.values()))
  N = sum(list(table.values())) 
  return sum([(value - mean)**k * frequency / N for value, frequency in table.items()]) 

sample = [100, 86, 51, 100, 95, 100, 12, 61, 0, 0, 12, 86, 0, 52, 62, 76, 91, 91, 62, 91, 65, 91, 9, 83, 67, 58, 56]
table = dict(Counter(sample))

print(empirical_central_moment(table, 3))
```

**Problem:** Instead of desired `-545.33983 ...` I'm getting `-26721.65147589292` and I just can't wrap my head around as to why I'm gettting wrong. Will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: empirical_central_moments takes 2 arguments, you didnt input k?

Comment: can't find any mistake at all. one little thing, N will be devided after the sum, but that makes no difference in calculations... how sure are you about the desired output value?

Comment: tried your input to a online moment calculator (https://www.vrcbuzz.com/moment-coefficient-of-kurtosis-calculator-for-grouped-data/). I think your answer is correct.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `scipy.stats.skew`  they also wrote how it is calculated in their lib...this results in an output of about -0,71 . [docu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Not sure what other answer you might be looking for. In general, and unless the purpose of this code is to exercise programming the logic of it, you don't need to reinvent the wheel and you'll be much faster and safer by doing something as simple as:

```
from scipy.stats import moment
sample = [100, 86, 51, 100, 95, 100, 12, 61, 0, 0, 12, 86, 0, 52, 62, 76, 91, 91, 62, 91, 65, 91, 9, 83, 67, 58, 56]
print(scipy.stats.moment(sample, moment=3, axis=0, nan_policy='propagate'))
```